# Develop and Deploy the software which made in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I know how to develop C# Winform application, but don't know anything about deployment/distribution for C#. Please say the technologies, procedures, and other setup for my objective.

Objective:

I like to develop and deploy[distribute] one small application software in C# .Net 3.5. I want some capabilities for the distribution that like other software products. ie. I want to develop software with installation wizard, set icon, and run even who didn't have any visual studio[Likewise, how the other software product like java games run without people must not installed the JDK.].

Comment: u want to install services??

Comment: You can create *Windows Installer* using Visual Studio

Comment: With a winform app, To deployment: you must publish in VS, VS will create a application for you  and then run  .exe.

Comment: @AccessDenied How can i create Windows Installer in VS. Are u telling about "Setup Project"?

Comment: @UdanPirappu yes, Output of the setup project would be a windows installer/MSI

Comment: @AccessDenied Share any tutorial if you know which clearly concise about Setup project.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you need an installer you will have to use some install wizard software. Examples are: InstallShield or WISE.

2) Otherwise you do not have to do much, just copy everything from your bin\Release folder to the other computer and run the exe file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WiX Toolset to make installers, which also integrate into build processes if you are using a build server. It can be used to make .exe, .msi and various other types of installations, including patches.

As far as I know it's one of the more commonly used installer frameworks, and you can find it here: http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Deploying Applications, Services, and Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) Here you can read about many of the ways you can develop and deploy services from Visual Studio 2013. There are plenty but all are well documented to suit the most different needs.

From the source

> - **Create a setup program**: You can create a setup program by using InstallShield Limited Edition, which is free. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx
> - **Deploy a desktop application**: By using ClickOnce deployment, you can publish a desktop application to a web server or a network
>     file share. Users can then install the application with a single click. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx