# How package and distribute C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, exe, packaging, software-distribution

I have to create a form for a task that is done by multiple people at the company I work for. Due to the circumstances, I have choosen Windows Forms and C# to make it. However, I'm not sure how I'm going to make the program available to my colleagues.

In Python, I use PyInstaller to create a .exe file and distribute my programs in a way that no one needs to install a Python interpreter to use it. Is there anything similar for C#?

Comment: Related: [Quick start: Deploy .NET Windows Desktop application using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Develop and Deploy the software which made in C#.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527002/develop-and-deploy-the-software-which-made-in-c-net)

Answer (score 1):

Right click project and choose publish.

There’s a lot of tutorials about it.